# Image of innerproduct unordered field?!

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

This might be totally stupid, but I have a problem regarding IPS and NLS. My problem is that as I understand, one does not assume that the image of the innerproduct is an ordered field..? In the wikipedia article on IPS the writer suggests $F$ to be $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ and
 $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle : V \times V \rightarrow F $.

My problem is that every inner product is supposed to give rise to a norm defined by $\sqrt {\langle v, v \rangle}$ which is supposed to fulfill the triangle inequality, but if ${\langle v, v \rangle} \in \mathbb{C}$ how can we then discuss any order at all and in particular a triangle inequality?

Furthermore, isn't $\mathbb{C}$ really regarded as a real IPS with ${\langle v, w \rangle}=v_1w_1 +v_2w_2$ where $v=v_1+iv_2$ and $w=w_1+iw_2$. One meaning that I would understand is that $V$ is a Complex linear space and that the image of $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is always real..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By assumption, the inner product is positive definite:
$$
\langle v, v \rangle \geq 0,
$$
for all $v \in V$.

So, even when the underlying field is $\mathbb C$, $\sqrt{\langle v, v \rangle}$ is a positive real number and it is the order from $\mathbb R$ that is relevant when talking about the triangle inequality.

Secondly, the usual inner product on $\mathbb C$ is not the one you have given. It is instead
$$
\langle v ,w \rangle = v \bar w = v_1 w_1 + v_2 w_2 + i(v_2w_1 -v_1 w_2),
$$
where $v = v_1 +i v_2$, $w=w_1 +i w_2$, and $v_1, v_2, w_1, w_2 \in \mathbb R$.

This inner product is not always real but the special case $\langle v, v \rangle = v_1^2 +v_2^2 $ is always real and positive.